# Testing significance between 2 survey response rates (R)

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis, significance

I have a survey that was split into 2, one group had pens, another didn't have pens. I want to compare if adding pens led to a significant increase in responses.

Attached are the results. N is the responses for 1 (with pens) and 2(without pens), Ttl is the total response number.

Im using R for analysis.

[image: Response Table]

Comment: Hi, please do not post tables as images. Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610=). The statistical test you are looking for is most likely a t test. To perform a t test, we need the standard deviations and the group sizes for both groups, or even better the raw data (all observations). There is `t.test` where you input just the raw data for each group and choose a method depending on your hypotheses. You will probably want to specify the argument `alternative = "greater"`.

Comment: What you want is a z test for proportions. Google it and use any of the million online stats calculators for comparing proportions. Generally, this is more a stats question IMO, not a coding question.